# Using css to format li tags within ol tags

Tags: html, css, styles, html-lists

I want to write a style sheet that will cause the li elements within any ol element to be numbered in an outline style:

the top-level li elements using uppercase Roman numerals, 
the next level uppercase letters, 
the next level lowercase Roman numerals, 
then lowercase letters, 
and decimal numerals at the fifth level.

This is my attempt at it, but the result is all the levels showing with upper-roman styling.

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ol > li {list-style: upper-roman}
    ol > li > li {list-style: upper-alpha}
    ol > li > li > li {list-style: lower-roman}
    ol > li > li > li > li {list-style: lower-alpha}
    ol > li > li > li > li > li {list-style: decimal}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>level 1
         <li>level 2
            <li>level 3
               <li>level 4
                  <li>level 5</li>
               </li>
            </li>
         </li>
       </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The nested `li` also need `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reason mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507385/using-css-to-format-li-tags-within-ol-tags#comment25452022_17507385), you need to nest `ol` tag as well. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTwXC/) to show.

### CSS

```
ol > li {
    list-style: upper-roman
}
ol > li li {
    list-style: upper-alpha
}
ol > li li li {
    list-style: lower-roman
}
ol > li li li li {
    list-style: lower-alpha
}
ol > li li li li li {
    list-style: decimal
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>level 1
            <ol>
                <li>level 2
                    <ol>
                        <li>level 3
                            <ol>
                                <li>level 4
                                    <ol>
                                        <li>level 5</li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting ordered lists (`<ol>`), not list items (`<li>`), so try this:

```
ol { list-style-type: upper-roman; }   
ol ol { list-style-type: upper-alpha; } 
ol ol ol {   list-style-type: decimal; } 
ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; } 
ol ol ol ol ol { list-style-type: lower-roman; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
ol > li > li {list-style: upper-alpha}
```

to this

```
ol > li > ol > li {list-style: upper-alpha}
```

and this

```
 <li>level 1
     <li>level 2
```

to

```
    <li>level 1
     <ol><li>level 2
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding IDs and Classes to your structure will help better.